# Significato e uso di "tenersi le mazzate" e altre espressioni simili

Tags: word-usage, meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Mille anni che sto qui*, di Mariolina Venezia, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> La sventurata moglie di Oronzio aveva due figli, ma soprattutto aveva quel marito disgraziato che si beveva tutto quello che lei portava a casa andando a fare la serva e la balia. Colino lo faceva lavorare ogni tanto, per pietà, ma erano piú le volte che non si presentava. Quando Mammalina si ribellava erano mazzate, ma lei non **se le teneva** e reagiva come una tigre. Li sentivano gridare da in mezzo alla piazza.

Non capisco del tutto bene cosa significa che questo personaggio, Mammalina, "non si teneva" le mazzate di suo marito, anche se posso intuire che abbia qualcosa a che vedere con il fatto che "reagiva come una tigre".

Ho cercato alla voce "tenere" di alcuni dizionari, ma ci sono tantissime accezioni che non riesco a vedere a quale possa corrispondere l'uso di "tenersi" che si fa nel testo. Qualcuno di voi me lo saprebbe spiegare? E poi, si tratta di un uso di "tenersi" più o meno comune?
Si potrebbe anche dire "tenersi un'altra cosa" con un significato simile? Se è così, potreste fare qualche esempio?

Ricercando su [Google Libri](https://books.google.es/books?id=M8eODAAAQBAJ&pg=PT42&lpg=PT42&dq=%22si+teneva+gli+insulti%22&source=bl&ots=lCLEvi_rDI&sig=ACfU3U0_U4ZdveKIkaHHSTzcednwHED0Rw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1trOX5qjpAhUJ-hQKHQLBA5AQ6AEwAXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22si%20teneva%20gli%20insulti%22&f=false) ne ho trovato questo esempio
(grassetto mio):

> Ed effettivamente tutti rimasero zitti mentre, sin quando si stava dirigendo verso di me, c'era stata gente che la canzonava e lei **si teneva gli insulti** silenziosa e triste.

Comment: Se capisco bene, questa è una frase simpatica che usa un italiano normalissimo: il marito dava mazzate a Mammalina, ma lei "non se le teneva", cioè le restituiva (magari solo a voce); in ogni caso non si limitava a subire.

Comment: Quindi il significato di "tenersi qualcosa" è "subire qualcosa senza reagire in nessun modo"? E in che senso questo ha un tono simpatico?

Comment: No @Charo, ho scritto il contrario: lei restituiva le mazzate che riceveva (cioè reagiva). La frase è simpatica perché parla delle mazzate (percosse) come di cose che si possono tenere. Questo uso di tenere è tutto sommato comune, l'esclamazione "tiè", con varie grafie, è assimilabile a "tieni!" o "prendi questo!" / "bèccati questo!", e si può usare assestando un colpo (anche verbale).

Comment: Prima volevo dire che "tenersi le mazzate" sarebbe subire le mazzate senza reagire, no?

Comment: Certo, certo. Vedi tu.

Comment: Si può anche usare "tenersi" con questo significato con altre cose? Per esempio, tenersi le beffe, tenersi gli insulti, tenersi le critiche, ecc.? Su [questo libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=M8eODAAAQBAJ&pg=PT42&lpg=PT42&dq=%22si+teneva+gli+insulti%22&source=bl&ots=lCLEvi_rDI&sig=ACfU3U0_U4ZdveKIkaHHSTzcednwHED0Rw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1trOX5qjpAhUJ-hQKHQLBA5AQ6AEwAXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22si%20teneva%20gli%20insulti%22&f=false) ho trovato un esempio di "si teneva gli insulti".

Comment: Sì, senz'altro si può, ma con moderazione, e quando si ricerca un linguaggio colorito. C'è un doppio passaggio: beffe insulti critiche non sono fisiche quindi non si possono "tenere", e poi non lo si fa volentieri quindi una frase così sottintende o prelude ad altro. Vedi anche, per esempio, "tenere botta", e ci sono altri casi.